# SQL Server 12 : error converting data type varchar to numeric vb6

Tags: vb6, sql-server-2012

I recently implemented a Database Upgrade Project. A migration of SQL Server 2000 databases to 2012.

In our UAT environment, all applications seems to work fine. But now in prod after the migration, one of the applications impacted by the upgrade is encountering a problem. The program is a VB6 application and the problem is that we don't have the source code. Another problem is that the sql query is hardcoded inside the application.

I managed to get the query where the error is firing using SQL Profiler.

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_SomeView 
WHERE ((ABS(some_balance + another_balance)/val_limit) * 100) BETWEEN '0' AND '999'
ORDER BY bal_no
```

The query above works fine in SQL Management Studio. However, this is not working in the application. I've tried to replicate it using a sample vb6 program and it is firing the same error. Please advise. Any suggestions, workaround will be much appreciated.

Comment: In the profiler look for the VB6 applications connection event and look at the various `set xxxx on/off` options it provides, copy-paste them into SSMS above the query and see if it runs. (Although I cant think of an option that would cause what your seeing, its the only other difference between the environments)

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. for the suggestion :-) although I still need a workaround for the vb application running in prod. All its query is actually hard-coded in the program so I am really having a hard time looking for a possible solution.